# Dynamic content in Joomla Articles

Tags: php, dynamic, joomla

I have some joomla articles. some values in that article has to be updated by data obtained through a soap call to other site. Is there any plugin available for joomla by which i  can embed custom php inside articles?? How can i do this.??

Answer (score 3):

To me, the ideal way is to create a traditional component that gets all the data. This component inserts these values in specified article ids. These articles act as "data containers".

Why create a traditional component? Because you'll be going to use libraries, error corrections and such and a component solution can be more robust. IMHO it's a good idea to avoid php logic in your editor panel.

Then, in the articles that are shown to users in the frontend, using [Include Content Item Joomla Plugin](http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/Include-Content-Item-plugin.php), you add `{include_content_item 123}`, being 123 the id of the article you inserted data you want to show in your component. Doing the {} call outputs the article which id is "123".

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Joomla plugin repository for "custom code in content"](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of such component, they are more or less the same.
I use Sourcerer, but pay attention as version of php is crucial sometimes.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051

Allows to insert php/js/css code to articles and modules.